# windows service hitting different link than what specified in service address

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services

I have installed a application on my machine which eventually installed some windows services which will be used by that application, there is UI screen in that application which enables to start the windows service and we can see the service address in the screen, but every time I start the service it is hitting a different link. I have debugged the code and there is no mention of that link which the service address is referring, is that a possibility that my application is importing some internet explorer or network settings? I am working on .Net 4.6.1 and my application is also build in 4.6.1

Comment: How and where are you seeing a difference?

Comment: *we can see the service address in the screen*: What do you mean by that? A windows service has no address.

Comment: @CodingYoshi windows service is installed on port 5040 on a server, that service is used by other client machines.

Comment: @BugFinder : I can see the difference TCPView and Process Explorer, it hitting port 80 with some other link and hence resulting in timeout.

Comment: Check the config file of the windows service and see if the link which is hitting port 80 is in there.

Comment: @CodingYoshi : I have already Checked the config file, base address mentioned there is of link which should hit 5040

Comment: Are you sure the machine you are connecting to doesnt have alternative dns names?